# Docker Swarm on Google Cloud - what configuration for file system, docker daemon, etc?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, terraform, docker-swarm

I'm looking to run a Docker Swarm cluster on Google Cloud. Does anyone know the ideal Docker configuration?

I just ran a default Ubuntu based gcp node and the Docker configuration seems to be on extfs. Is this fine or should I be configuring xfs, etc (which I'm not sure how to do in a Google cloud environment)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Docker swarm is meant to abstract away the hardware layer, I don't think the file system matters. It will work on all of them as far as I know

you can use XFS or ext 3 or 4.